# Android - Resize image before loading to ImageView to avoid OOM issues

Tags: java, android

How can one reduce image size on imageview after selecting from gallery/photos?. Otherwise selected large images are causing OOM issues.

**Selecting Intent**

```
SelectImageGallery1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image1 From Gallery"), 1);
    }
}
```

**Setting to ImageView**:

```
{
    Uri uri = I.getData();
    try {
        bitmap1 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
        imageView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally made it to resolve it using glide as follows for those who might need it in future.
Selecting Intent

```
SelectImageGallery1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image1 From Gallery"), 1);
    }
}
```

Setting Image to Imageview Using Glide

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int RC, int RQC, Intent I) {
        super.onActivityResult(RC, RQC, I);
        if (RC == 1 && RQC == RESULT_OK && I != null && I.getData() != null) {
            Uri uri = I.getData();
            RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
                    .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_RGB_565)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);

            Glide.with(this)
                    .setDefaultRequestOptions(options)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load(uri)
                    .centerInside()
                    .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>(512, 512) {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap bitmap1, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                            imageView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
                            MainActivity.this.bitmap1 = bitmap1;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
                        }
                    });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently` part of the documentation, specifically the `Load a Scaled Down Version into Memory` (https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap#load-bitmap)

By setting the `inSampleSize` you can control the size of the `Bitmap` before it's loaded.

From the docs:

```java
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

The docs is using a resource as example but you should be able to use a `ContentResolver` by grabbing an `InputStream` and use `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(...)` instead

```java
ContentResolver cr = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
InputStream is = cr.openInputStream(uri);
```

Comment: Thanks @patrick. I have read all that but I don't understand how to implement it

Answer (score 0):

Use picasso for this purpose

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

And to load images use this code

```
Picasso.get()
    .load(R.drawable.landing_screen)
    .resize(50, 50)
    .into(imageView1);
```

For more information go to the link :

https://square.github.io/picasso/

You can use this also for loading images asynchronously from web without any HTTP request by yourself.

Comment: Thanks @Abdur Rahman. Where is the picasso code supposed to be put?. I have several imageviews for that matter.